# game name combining cell and monopoly

Tags: names

i can't think of a name about cells except cellnopoly but almost everybody has that one and it has to be unique (p.s. i'm using a monopoly board for my games).

Answer (score 5):

- Cellular Monopoly
- Lord of the Cells
- Robber barons of Cellicon valley
- All your cells are belong to us
- Cell me out.

Comment: You should get a job as a copy writer...

Comment: CELL ME OUT I LKIE THAT ONE THANK YOU